# Android Room relacion uno a muchos, lista vacía en relación

Tags: android, kotlin, room

He visto distintos posts en Stackoverflow y tutoriales varios, pero soy incapaz de que la lista de precios de la relación no salga vacía.

Tengo dos entidades. Game y Price. Cada juego (game) tiene 1 o varios precios (price).

Entidad Game:

```
@Entity(tableName = "game_table")
data class Game(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val appId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val isWindows: Boolean,
    val isMac: Boolean,
    val isLinux: Boolean,
    val gameUrl: String
)
```

Entidad Price:

```
@Entity(tableName = "price_table", foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Game::class,
        parentColumns = ["appId"],
        childColumns = ["appId"],
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )
])
data class Price(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val idPrice: Int = 0,
    val appId: Int,
    val originalPrice: Double,
    val currentPrice: Double,
    val discount: Int
)
```

Relación entre entidades:

```
data class GameAndPrice(
    @Embedded val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "appId",
        entityColumn = "idPrice"
    )
    val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
)
```

Hasta aquí creo que tengo todo correcto.

GameDao:

```
@Dao
interface GameDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(game: Game)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(price: Price)

    @Update
    fun update(game: Game)

    @Delete
    fun delete(game: Game)

    @Query("DELETE FROM game_table")
    fun deleteAllGames()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM game_table ORDER BY appId DESC")
    fun getAllGames(): LiveData<List<Game>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM game_table ORDER BY appId DESC")
    fun getAllGamesAndPrices(): LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>
}
```

El repositorio:

```
class GameRepository(private val gameDao: GameDao) {

    val getAllGames: LiveData<List<Game>> = gameDao.getAllGames()
    val getAllPrices: LiveData<List<Price>>  = gameDao.getAllPrices()
    val getAllGamesAndPrices: LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>  = gameDao.getAllGamesAndPrices()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.insert(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(price: Price) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.insert(price)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun update(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.update(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun delete(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.delete(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteAllGames() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.deleteAllGames()
        }
    }
}
```

El ViewModel:

```
class GameViewModel(private val repository: GameRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val gameList: LiveData<List<Game>> = repository.getAllGames
    val priceList: LiveData<List<Price>>  = repository.getAllPrices
    val gamesAndPricesList: LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>  = repository.getAllGamesAndPrices

    fun insert(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insert(game) }
    fun insert(price: Price) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insert(price) }
    fun update(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.update(game) }
    fun delete(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.delete(game) }
    fun deleteAllGames()   = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteAllGames() }
}

class GameViewModelFactory(private val repository: GameRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(GameViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return GameViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Si no estoy equivocado, sólamente necesito insertar el juego (game) por un lado `ViewModel.insert(game)` y los precios por el otro `ViewModel.insert(price)`. La relación debería ocuparse de rellenar `val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()`.

Pero cuando observo e imprimo mediante Log `gameViewModel.gamesAndPricesList.observe(this, Observer { Log.d("onCreate", it[0].listPrice.toString()) })` muestra una lista vacía (a pesar de que el precio se ha introducido correctamente en la tabla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay dos errores:

1. `entityColumn` debe ser el campo que usas como foreignKey. En este caso sería "appId"

   ```
   data class GameAndPrice(
       @Embedded val game: Game,
       @Relation(
           parentColumn = "appId",
           entityColumn = "idPrice" // este es el error
       )
       val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
   )
   ```
2. Pero si tratas de corregirlo vas a caer en el segundo error porque los campos relacionados no pueden tener el mismo nombre.

Entonces la solución es cambiar el nombre de uno de esos dos campos. Ejemplo:

```
@Entity(tableName = "price_table", foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Game::class,
        parentColumns = ["appId"],
        childColumns = ["priceAppId"],
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )
])
data class Price(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val idPrice: Int = 0,
    val priceAppId: Int,
    val originalPrice: Double,
    val currentPrice: Double,
    val discount: Int
)
```

Ahora corriges la relación y funcionará como esperabas

```
data class GameAndPrice(
    @Embedded val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "appId",
        entityColumn = "priceAppId"
    )
    val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
)
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!! Muchas gracias!